# what is wrong with this webviewclient

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, webclient, webviewclient

This is a part of code, I click a link like `<a href="www.abc/file.php?download&sn=6"></a>` , it should go if() but it always run the else() one,
help me to check the code thx :)

```
public class WebClient : WebViewClient
    {

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {

            if (url.Contains("download"))
            {
                var url2 = "https://www.google.com.tw/";
                view.LoadUrl(url2);

            }
            else
            {
                //return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                view.LoadUrl(url);

            }
            return true;
        }
```

[my complete code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444934/how-to-download-files-in-webview) except the webviewclient part,it's different in this case.

Comment: You can check the spelling name of "download" text in url and after that debug your code.

Comment: @Y2H The link you have in the description is not working, did you try a link that works?

Comment: I'm not sure about your meaning, but "download" is not a variable in url,it's static string.

Comment: To Johny:that is fake one , here is real one :http://www.recc.com.tw/recc_app/ch/lecturer_curriculum_edit.php?a=Modify&s=151&opp=download&kind=curriculum_file&ds=132

Comment: I tried with certain real url, but didn't reproduced the problem. Could you please debug to check: 1. Whether `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` function get called. 2. Whether the value of `url` argument contains substring `download`.

Comment: To Elvis: May i ask how to check url value that webview load?